# How to predict and extract R Squared with .lm.fit?

Tags: r, lm

As the title suggest, I have seen some user mentioned that `.lm.fit()` functions has an advantage of more speed than a regular `lm()`, but when i look deeper at `.lm.fit()` in help, it is supposed to be a fitter functions, it returns a **set of list** instead of a **model**, which makes me to think is it still possible to extract components like R squared, Adj R Squared, and lastly do a `predict()` out of it?

Below is sample data and executions:

```
test_dat <- data.frame(y = rnorm(780, 20, 10))
for(b in 1:300){
  name_var <- paste0("x",b)
  test_dat[[name_var]] <- rnorm(780, 0.01 * b, 5)
}

tic()
obj_lm <- lm(y ~ ., data = test_dat)
print(class(obj_lm))
print(summary(obj_lm)$r.squared)
print(summary(obj_lm)$adj.r.squared)
predict(obj_lm)
toc() #approximately 0.4 seconds

tic()
datm <- as.matrix(test_dat)
obj_lm_fit <- .lm.fit(cbind(1,datm[,-1]), datm[,1])
print(class(obj_lm_fit))
toc() #approximately 0.2 seconds
```

Comment: Not an answer but true times are even more favorable to `.lm.fit`, you are also timing `as.matrix` and `cbind`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Functions `predict` and `resid` are generic and since `.lm.fit` returns an object of class `"list"`, all you have to do is to write methods implementing the definitions of what you want. Below are methods to compute fitted values, residuals and R^2.

```r
set.seed(2023)    # make the results reproducible
test_dat <- data.frame(y = rnorm(780, 20, 10))
for(b in 1:300){
  name_var <- paste0("x",b)
  test_dat[[name_var]] <- rnorm(780, 0.01 * b, 5)
}

obj_lm <- lm(y ~ ., data = test_dat)

datm <- as.matrix(test_dat)
obj_lm_fit <- .lm.fit(cbind(1,datm[,-1]), datm[,1])

#------------------------------------------------------------------------
# the methods for objects of class "list"
#
fitted.list <- function(object, X) {
  X %*% coef(object)
}
resid.list <- residuals.list <- function(object, X, y) {
  y_fitted <- fitted(object, X)
  y - y_fitted
}
rsquared <- function(x, ...) UseMethod("rsquared")
rsquared.default <- function(x, ...) {
  summary(x)$r.squared
}
rsquared.list <- function(object, X, y) {
  e <- resid.list(object, X, y)
  1 - sum(e^2)/sum( (y - mean(y))^2 )
}

rsquared(obj_lm_fit, cbind(1,datm[,-1]), datm[,1])
#> [1] 0.3948863
rsquared(obj_lm)
#> [1] 0.3948863
```

<sup>Created on 2023-01-03 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

## Edit 1

Added method to also calculate adj.R2

```
adj_rsquared_list <- function(object, X, y){
  r2 <- rsquared.list(object, X, y)
  k <- ncol(X) - 1
  n <- nrow(X)  
  rate_of_error <- (1 - r2) * (n - 1) / (n - k - 1)
  adj_r2 <- 1 - rate_of_error
  return(adj_r2)
}

adj_rsquared_list(obj_lm_fit, cbind(1,datm[,-1]), datm[,1])
#> [1] 0.01590061
```

---

## Edit 2

After the edit by [Jovan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8848227/jovan), I have changed `fitted.list` above to use `coef()`, a function that extracts the first arguments list member `"coefficients"`, if it exists, and rewrote the default and list methods of `rsquared` to accept a `adj` argument. The code to compute the adjusted R^2 is a copy&paste of Jovan's code.

```r
rsquared <- function(x, ...) UseMethod("rsquared")
rsquared.default <- function(x, adj = FALSE, ...) {
  if(adj) {
    summary(x)$adj.r.squared
  } else summary(x)$r.squared
}
rsquared.list <- function(object, X, y, adj = FALSE) {
  e <- resid.list(object, X, y)
  r2 <- 1 - sum(e^2)/sum( (y - mean(y))^2 )
  if(adj) {
    k <- ncol(X) - 1
    n <- nrow(X)  
    rate_of_error <- (1 - r2) * (n - 1) / (n - k - 1)
    adj_r2 <- 1 - rate_of_error
    adj_r2
  } else r2
}

# same as above
rsquared(obj_lm_fit, cbind(1,datm[,-1]), datm[,1])
#> [1] 0.3948863
rsquared(obj_lm)
#> [1] 0.3948863

# new, `adj = TRUE`
rsquared(obj_lm_fit, cbind(1,datm[,-1]), datm[,1], adj = TRUE)
#> [1] 0.01590061
rsquared(obj_lm, adj = TRUE)
#> [1] 0.01590061
```

<sup>Created on 2023-01-03 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for adding this example, I am glad that it can be reproduced this way, I added also the methods for computing Adj R2 above!

Comment: @Jovan Great edit, it definitely improves my answer. I have used it to make `rsquared` more general, in the 2nd edit there's a version that computes both R^2 and the adjusted R^2.